# pytest should run module_B which is imported in test_func of test_module_A

Tags: python, pytest

Here is my Code

pkg :- A

```
#test_module_A.py

def test_A1():
    print('abc')

def test_A2():
    import B.test_module_B


pkg:- B
#test_module_B.py

def test_B1():
    print('def')
```

I am running test_module_A from pycharm using pytest

output

abc

However i would like the output to be

```
abc
def
```

can anyone help me....

In real scenario 
test_module_B is dynamic among 100s of module present inside package.

I would like pytest to redirect its control from A2() to module_B and then executes it entirely and again come back to module A and executes any remaining functions......

Comment: Why so complicated? `pytest` can execute multiple modules at a time: `pytest test_module_A.py test_module_B.py`. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You are importing `B.test_module_B`, but you are then not executing the actual test. I presume that you want the following:

```
def test_A2():
    import B.test_module_B
    B.test_module_B.test_B1()
```

Comment: This will execute test_B1() as a normal function... I want pytest to recognize this as his test func... For Ex when i run test_module_A ... it should say collected 3 items instead it says collected 2 items....why i am focusing on this is because test_b1() is parameterized and as per this approach it says please pass argument because my test_b1() is somethig like this @pytest.mark.parametrize('args', [
    (10, 8),
    (1, 6),
    (7, 42),
])
def test_B1(args):
    print()
    print(f'args ran...{args}')